# Why doesn't the overload function of [] function here?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

```
#include "stdafx.h"    
#include <iostream>    
using namespace std;    
#include <string.h>    

class Array    
{    
public:    
    int Length;    
    char *Arrp;    
    Array(char *str)    
    {    
        Length=strlen(str);    
        Arrp=str;    
    }    
    char & operator[](int index);    
};    
    char & Array::operator[](int index)    
    {    
        if(index>=Length||index<0)    
        {    
            cout<<"Index "<<index<<" error."<<endl;    
            return Arrp[0];    
        }    
        return Arrp[index];    
    }    
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])    
{    
    Array a("Good");    
    cout<<a.Arrp[6]<<endl;    
    return 0;    
}
```

It doesn't get into the overload function of [] at all. I compare it with lots of examples but what I write never functions.

How can I proceed further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not calling the overloaded function but are directly reading the array itself.

Try:

```
cout<<a[6]<<endl;
```

Comment: Furthermore, make the attributes 'Length' and 'Arrp' private